# X-Robots-Tag: noindex on an HTTP 302 response to remove subdomain

Tags: google-search-console, google-index, http-headers, noindex, 302-redirect

This very related to this question ["X-Robots-Tag: noindex" on an HTTP 301 response](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/50575/x-robots-tag-noindex-on-an-http-301-response), however I don't see a definitive answer.

We have subdomains we use for our affiliate links, the affiliates publish a link to the subdomain which in turn 302 redirects to the main site.

However the subdomains are being indexed (as you usually find with 302 redirected URLs) and I would like to remove them from from the index.

I thought about removing them in GWT using URL removal, but I think they may become indexed again, so I was wondering about the possibility of using an X-Robots-Tag HTTP header in conjunction with the 302 redirect.

Can you use both together, or will only 1 be seen? If both are seen, will the noindex work; or would you just go the route of removing in GWT?

Comment: Why not use a 301? There's no reason why you can't send both headers (it's just another header in the response). If Google doesn't "see it" it's because it's deliberately ignoring it.

Comment: We don't want to use 301's or direct links as we don't want the links form our affiliates to pass any weight to our main site.

Answer (score 6):

As of December 2022, Google **will** respect a `X-Robots-Tag` HTTP Response header that comes as part of a HTTP 302 response - Google Search Console will report: *"Indexing allowed? No: 'noindex' detected in 'X-Robots-Tag' http header"*.

I've verified this in my role as a developer on theguardian.com, ie, having [added](https://github.com/guardian/frontend/pull/25757) a `X-Robots-Tag` HTTP Response header to the redirecting url https://www.theguardian.com/business/series/buying-black/latest :

```
% curl --silent -I https://www.theguardian.com/business/series/buying-black/latest
HTTP/2 302
location: /business/2022/dec/14/buying-black-history-could-help-everyone
...
x-robots-tag: noindex
...
```

...then even attempting to explicitly index the page in Google Search Console fails, which is exactly what we want:

[image: Google Search Console says: "Page cannot be indexed: Excluded by ‘noindex’ tag"]

So, thankfully it's no longer necessary to avoid 302 redirects (eg using an awful Javascript redirect) just to get Google to *not* index a redirecting url.

Comment: Very interesting, thanks for the update.

Answer (score 3):

Google considers the status code *before* looking at everything else, so the `X-Robots-Tag` will be ignored. We did some test a year ago with a client and this was **not working**.

The strategy that we used was to remove manually the URLs in the Search Console and add the folder to the `robots.txt`. An alternative is to use javascript redirects, but this is not very user friendly.